# Return name of model an authenticated user belongs to

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have custom user models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Supplier(User):
    company_name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_domain=models.CharField(max_length=30)
        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'supplier'
        verbose_name_plural = 'suppliers'
        
class Worker(User):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('1', 'Admin'),
        ('2', 'Regular'),
    )
    is_hub_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'worker'
        verbose_name_plural = 'workers'
```

Views.py

```
class AccountType(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print(type(request.user))
        return Response({'account_type':"supplier"} , status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED )
```

and I have created `/auth/account_type` which is supposed to return the type authenticated user
I would like it to be able to return a response like

```
{
    "account_type": "Supplier"
}
```

where the word `Supplier` is got from the name of the model class it belongs to. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: So by all means I have to keep the account type in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `property` to your custom user class that returns the name of the related class. `hasattr(obj, '<class_name>')` will return `True` if `obj` has a one-to-one relationship with the class/model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def subclass(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'supplier'):
            return 'Supplier'
        elif hasattr(self, 'worker'):
            return 'Worker'
        return None


class AccountType(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'account_type': request.user.subclass}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

Comment: It seems to return only the User i.e `{
    "account_type": "User"
}` even when I authenticate with a `Supplier` account or `Worker`

Comment: @iamafasha added a potential solution

Answer (score 0):

this will give you class name `print(request.user.__class__.__name__)`